# CMake: Target Link Libraries

Tags: qt, cmake, vtk

How can I link the library to the executable that is being made? 
Please excuse if this is a simple problem, I am *very new* to CMake.

I seem to be having problems attaching VTK+QT to an existing project. The problems lies with the `target_link_libraries` lines, claiming the target is not built in the directory. However, it must be because it builds an executable without the additions (due to the `set(EXECUTABLE_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})` right?).
If I attempt to make another executable using `add_executable`, it complains saying there is already one, so why can't CMake detect it?

After much googling and scraping here, I can only seem to find people who are using the `add_executable` after `target_link_libraries`. So as far as I can see, this doesn't apply to this case.

Here is the `CMakeFile.txt` - Which is an amalgamation of a current `CMakeFile` and the `CMakeFile` from the VTK examples:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

if(POLICY CMP0020)
    cmake_policy(SET CMP0020 NEW)
endif()

set(PROJECT_NAME "BRDFViz")
set(EXECUTABLE_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

project(
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
  VERSION 1.0
  LANGUAGES CXX
  )

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)

## Assimp
find_package(assimp REQUIRED)

# VTK
find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})

## GLM
set(GLM_FIND_REQUIRED TRUE)
find_path(
  GLM_INCLUDE_DIRS "glm/glm.hpp"
  )
find_package_handle_standard_args(
  GLM
  DEFAULT_MSG
  GLM_INCLUDE_DIRS
  )

## libpng, PNG++
find_package(PNG REQUIRED)
set(png++_FIND_REQUIRED TRUE)
find_path(
  png++_INCLUDE_DIRS
  NAMES "png++/color.hpp" "png++/png.hpp"
  )
find_package_handle_standard_args(
  png++
  DEFAULT_MSG
  png++_INCLUDE_DIRS
  )

## libjpeg
find_package(JPEG REQUIRED)

## OpenEXR
find_package(OpenEXR REQUIRED)
add_subdirectory(src)

if(${VTK_VERSION} VERSION_GREATER "6" AND VTK_QT_VERSION VERSION_GREATER "4")
    set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
    find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
else()
    message([FATAL_ERROR] "BRDFViz requires VTK 7 and QT 5 or higher. \n Exiting processing and generation") 
endif()

 include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
file(GLOB UI_FILES *.ui)
file(GLOB QT_WRAP *.h)
if(${VTK_VERSION} VERSION_GREATER "6" AND VTK_QT_VERSION VERSION_GREATER "4")
    qt5_wrap_ui(UISrcs ${UI_FILES})
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Gt5::Core Qt5::Gui) 
else()
    message([FATAL_ERROR] "BRDFViz requires VTK 7 and QT 5 or higher. \n Exiting processing and generation")
endif()

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you create an executable target in the `src/` subdirectory (in its `CMakeLists.txt`)? Then you should place `target_link_libraries` in the script where you create the target. Exactly that CMake tells you in the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set(EXECUTABLE_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})` command barely creates a variable `EXECUTABLE_NAME` with the value of another variable, `PROJECT_NAME`. It does not tell CMake to build an actual executable, so you actually should use `add_executable`. However, it should really go before `target_link_libraries` although I am not completely sure CMake can't handle the opposite order.

> If I attempt to make another executable using "add_executable", it
>   complains saying there is already one, so why can't CMake detect it?

It seems that your problem is caused by the fact that you actually have `add_executable` within another `CMakeLists.txt` which is located in your `src` subdirectory which you add via `add_subdirectory(src)`. One solution to your problem could be to move `target_link_libraries` to `CMakeLists.txt` within your `src` directory and also move `add_subdirectory(src)` to the end of `CMakeLists.txt` which you have shown: that way in `CMakeLists.txt` which is inside `src` subdirectory you would have access to all the variables defined in the parent `CMakeLists.txt` + CMake should stop complaining about the inability to link libraries because the target is built in another directory.

Comment: Thank you very much